# convert conv1D to Conv2D with GRU

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I learning to convert my CNN 1D achitecture with GRU to CNN2 with GRU.

Here is the code In python 3 with Tensorflow keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 5, activation='relu',
                        input_shape=(None, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GRU(32, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                              steps_per_epoch=500,
                              epochs=20,
                              validation_data=val_gen,
                              validation_steps=val_steps)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the shape of `float_data`?

Comment: 23,154 for CNN 2D

Comment: @giser_yugang  for the cnn the size will be 23,154